# Android TV -Can I change the location of badge drawable on android tv in BrandedSupportFragment?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

By default android TV leanback library is showing badge drawable on the top right corner of the screen but I want to change its location on screen. Is it possible to do it in the android TV leanback library?

The badge drawable is set in `BrandedSupprotFragment`. I want to put the image just after the title/hover card.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own titleview to replace the default title view. Your own title view should implement the `TitleViewAdapter.Provider` interface. And to use it, first you need to set it in your theme.xml like this:

```
<style name="YOUR.OWN.STYLE" parent = "Theme.Leanback">
    ...
    <item name="browseTitleViewLayout">@layout/your_title_view</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Lastly, call the `installTitleView(...)` method in your `onCreateView(...)` method and you should be good to go.